# Why createshadowroot is giving me a different result then attachshadow?

Tags: css, web, shadow-dom

I'm having an issue with shadow dom. I`ve found a tutorial that seems a bit old about shadow dom and it`s using createshadowroot. I`ve been notified that createshadowroot is deprecated and should be replaced by attachshadow.

The problem i`m having is that attachshadow does not produce the desired effect while using templates. It`s not copying the content of my elements into the html.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var nameTags = document.querySelectorAll('.nameTag');

for (i = 0; i < nameTags.length; ++i)
{
    //var shadow = nameTags[i].attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    var shadow = nameTags[i].createShadowRoot();
    var template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');

    var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

    console.log(shadow);
    console.log(template);
    console.log(template.content);
    console.log(clone);

    shadow.appendChild(clone);
}
```

**result with createShadowRoot**

[image: result with createShadowRoot]

**result with attachShadow**

[image: result with attachShadow]

The content is not being copied correctly with attachShadow yet it`s createShadowRoot that is deprecated. I don`t want to code everything with createShadowRoot since it`s support will be gone sometime in the future. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

With Shadow DOM v1 `attachShadow()`, you should now use `<slot>` instead of `<content>` inside the `<template>` element in order to insert some content from the light DOM.

```
<template>
    <slot name="first"></slot>
</template>
...
<div id=host>
    <div slot="first">Name</div>
</div>
```

Look at the [difference of use between `<slot>` and `<content>`](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#insertion-points-v0-vs-slots-v1) by Hayato or a [description of the `<slot>` tag](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#slots) by Bidel.